# Getting error SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis while creating table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Here's what I did:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(CUST_ID NUMBER(6)
                      CUST_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
                      CUST_ADDR VARCHAR2(50),
                      CUST_CELL NUMBER(10),
                      CREATED _BY VARCHAR2(50),
                      CONSTRAINT CUST_ID_PK PRIMARY KEY(CUST_ID),
                      CONSTRAINT CUST_NAME_UK UNIQUE KEY(CUST_NAME));
```

What's wrong?

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT.  " CREATED _BY "  space.

Answer (score 0):

You have some issue in your query.
First, the CUST_ID and CUST_NAME you are missing a comma.

```
CUST_ID NUMBER(6), <-------- here
CUST_NAME VARCHAR2(50),
```

2- CREATED _BY you have a space between CREATED and _BY.

Let's start with this and let us know.

Thanks